# Caching select query data on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, memcached

I am writing an express app, where I'm pushing data from my views to a database. But most of the data is mapped to some other data in database tables.

For example, is a choose student name drop down-  once you choose the student by his name , a drop down below - will show all roles that he is allowed for.

So I'm following this pattern of

```
app.post('\action1', function(req,res){
  function querySomething(){
    var defered = Q.defer();
      connection.query(some_select_query,defered.makeNodeResolver());
      return defered.promise;
    }

  function querySomethingElse(){
    var defered = Q.defer();
      connection.query(some_other_select_query,defered.makeNodeResolver());
      return defered.promise;
    }

   Q.all([querySomething(), querySomethingElse()]).then((results,err) => {
       connection.release()
       if(results){
          res.render('some_view.ejs', {
             result1:results[0][0],
             result2:results[1][0]
          });
       }
       else{
         res.render('error.ejs',{});
       }
   })
})
```

Now the problem is that I have to follow this pattern of selecting something from multiple tables, pass all these function to a promise- and when the results is passed back, goto my view with all those result objects - so that I can use them in my view - as a means of doing drop downs dependent on one another.

Sometimes I have to re-write this multiple times.

Doing a select query like this would be performance intensive especially if all views are using the result of the same query.

Is there any way I can build a cached data store on my express server side code and query that instead of the actual database??

If there is an insert or an update - i will refresh this store and just do a new select * that one time.

What libraries are there on top of express which will help me do this??

Does mysql-cache does the same thing?? I'm also using connection pooling with createPool.

How do I achieve this - or do I just restore to using big mvc's like sails to rewrite my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [apiCache](https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache) npm module.

"**Sometimes I have to re-write this multiple times.**"

Based on the business need, you may want to handle each use case separately and this scenario doesn't deal with caching.

**Doing a select query like this would be performance intensive especially if all views are using the result of the same query.**

This is a classic example for the need of [server-side](https://goenning.net/2016/02/10/simple-server-side-cache-for-expressjs/) caching.